# How do I stop this very sharp corner when using custom textured brushes in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I am trying to get comfortable with custom brushes, mainly using textured brushes from PNG files. And yet, when I set the stroke depth order to 3D location, I get these huge noticeable spikes as if the brush is square shaped rather than circular like I want it. What am I doing wrong? I just want the brushes to not be drawn under each other if I make multiple strokes in the same area and I certainly don't want these weird spikey square like corners.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late but I still want to help if I can. It seems you might have "self overlap" checked. You can find this option in the Material Properties tab under "Surface" -> "Stroke". Make sure you turn it off so there won't be any overlapping. This option is often turned on for custom brushes as some may use png files that aren't fully transparent, which leads to brushes having white parts in it. Hope this helped!

[image: self overlap location]